# sqlite3_exec returns 1 although query is right

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Here's my code

```
std::string dbFileName = "GalleryDB.sqlite";

    int doesFileExist = _access(dbFileName.c_str(), 0);
    int res = sqlite3_open(dbFileName.c_str(), &db);
    if (res != SQLITE_OK) {
        db = nullptr;
        std::cout << "Failed to open DB" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if (doesFileExist == 0) {
        char* sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE USERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , NAME TEXT NOT NULL);";
        char** errMessage = nullptr;
        res = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement, nullptr, nullptr, errMessage);
        if (res != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << res;
            std::cout << "ERROR! CANT CREATE USERS" << '\n';

        }
}
```

Altough my query to create the users table is correct, and it does create the table it always returns 1. What's the reason? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Try passing the address of a `char *` as last argument and inspect its contents afterwards.

Comment: What's the error? Though you're not passing the error message string pointer correctly...